# How can I set a unique UUID for my PickedFile?

Tags: flutter, dart, uuid

I'm trying to give an image uploaded from camera a unique id before uploading to Firestore.
I've been using Reed Barger's https://www.udemy.com/course/build-a-social-network-with-flutter-and-firebase/ tutorial but some of the code he used has been deprecated. In this case, image compression.
His code to compress and set unique image id was

```
compressImage() async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;
    Im.Image imageFile = Im.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
    final compressedImageFile = File('$path/img_$postId.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(imageFile, quality: 85));
    setState(() {
      file = compressedImageFile;
    });
  }
```

The libraries he used include

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Im;
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
```

His variables were

```
 File file;
 String postId = Uuid().v4();
```

Since then, the `image_picker` library allows me to compress the image by seting the `imageQuality` so there's no need for the `image.dart` package. How can I modify my code (below) to set a unique image id in the format Reed used?

```
 PickedFile file;
  String postId = Uuid().v4();

  handleTakePhoto() async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    file = (await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: 675.0,
      maxWidth: 960,
      imageQuality: 85,
    ));
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;
    final compressedImageFile = File('$path/img_$postId.jpg');
    setState(() {
      this.file = file;
      file = compressedImageFile;
    });
  }
```

As it is, it returns an error that `compressedFileImage` can't be assigned to type `PickedFile`.
I've tried adding the cast `as PickedFile` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're creating a `File` instead of a `PickedFile`:

```dart
final compressedImageFile = File('$path/img_$postId.jpg');
```

Just change it to:

```dart
final compressedImageFile = PickedFile('$path/img_$postId.jpg');
```

Comment: That gives a new directory but returns error `Cannot open file, path = ''newdirectory.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

This has worked so far. I've created a variable  `File storedImage;` Then changed

```
setState(() {
      this.file = file;
      file = compressedImageFile;
    }
```

to

```
setState(() {
     this.file = file;
     storedImage = File(file.path);
     storedImage = compressedImageFile;
     print(compressedImageFile); //For debugging
   }
```

The print statement gives me the new uuid and name.